# Add a number to every item in list

Tags: functions, list

How do I add a number, say 2, to every item in a list?

```el
(setq x '(1 2))

(+ 2 x)

(mapcar '2+ x)

(loop for i in x
      do (+ 2 i))

(dolist (i x)
  (+ 2 i))
```

None of the above work.

Comment: `(+ 2 x)` doesn't work because `+` takes numbers as arguments and returns their sum, and `(mapcar '2+ x)` doesn't work because there is no built-in function called `2+` (though you could define it yourself). The two loops work, but you are not saving the results of their computation anywhere, so the results are lost.

Comment: This Q and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55440/105 are essentially the same question. One of them should be deleted. (@Basil: would you like to consolidate the underlying question as a community question?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solutions:

```el
(mapcar (lambda (entry) (+ entry 2)) x)
```

```el
(mapcar (apply-partially #'+ 2) x)
```

And if you need to update `x`, then `setq` it to the result of one of the above forms, e.g.:

```el
(setq x (mapcar (apply-partially #'+ 2) x))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not very elegant (there's probably a much simpler answer) but this should work:

```
(setq x '(1 2 3 4))

(defun add-one (x)
  "Add 1 to each element of list X"
  (setq counter 0)
  (setq res x)
  (while (< counter (length x))
    (setcar (nthcdr counter res) (1+ (car (nthcdr counter x))))
    (setq counter (1+ counter)))
  res)

(add-one x)
```

Comment: Never destructively modify (e.g. using `setcar`) a quoted constant list, such as `'(1 2 3 4)`, otherwise the constant will be modified globally and the same code may behave differently in each run. Instead, either initialise `x` to a new list, such as `(list 1 2 3 4)`, before modifying it, or accumulate changes in a new list and set that as the value of `x`, thus replacing its old value.

Comment: Your looping logic is unidiomatic Elisp and inefficient, as it traverses the same list from the start for each element access. Idiomatic Elisp uses `dolist`, `mapc`, `mapcar`, or successive calls to `cdr` to go from one list element to another, without the need for indices or traversing the entire length each time. Lists are not random-access like arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the input! (Noobs make noob mistakes ;))